# Doing a join such that the first row only is returned

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a case of Linq, where upon joining two tables, I'm getting 10 rows of data. But I really care about the first one, is there a way to limit it to return only 1 row?

Is there a general join operation like this? For example, is there something like FIRST OUTER JOIN, or something ...?

Comment: You do the join as you normally would, then do a `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` right after.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - In order for that to return the expected results, he better be specifying an `Order` somewhere...

Comment: True that - unless he doesn't care about the order and wants just "any" - unlikely though. No order was specified in the question though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = (<your query>).First();
```

Or if you want to guard against an empty sequence;

```
var result = (<your query>).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, FirstOrDefault doesn't guard against null... it guards against empty sequence.

Comment: Good point, I was thinking of whenever you actually try to access your result, but I guess it's not like you would ever get there if you used First() on an empty sequence. Will update the wording - cheers.